# Auto adjust sites on sharepoint 2013 to fit screen, when display items option on windows is set to "Larger - 150%"

Tags: page-layout, image-display

Is there any way to auto adjust a web page on Sharepoint 2013, given that Windows Display Style is often switched to "Larger - 150%"?

[image]

It doesn't have to do with screen resolution, so I wonder if there's any solution to let the sitepage auto adjust itself to fit the screen. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use javascript in a .txt file linked to a content editor web part.

In your case, you would probably want to set it to wi + px.

My code usually looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {


//  adjust navigation lists and  other tables to match nav bar width - Change sizes on smaller screens:
var wi = $(window).innerWidth(); 
var navwi = $(".Navigation").width();
var NavHeight = $(".Navigation").height();
var btnwi = $("input").width();
var HeadHeight = $("#MSOImageWebPart_WebPartWPQ3").height();
var NameHeight = $("#MSOImageWebPart_WebPartWPQ11").height();


        $("#MSOImageWebPart_WebPartWPQ3").css({
        width: wi + "px",
        });

        $(".ms-WPBody").css({
        width: wi + "px",
        margin: "auto"
        });

        $(".navigation").css({
        width: wi -50 + "px",
        margin: "auto"
        });

        $(".s4-wpTopTable").css({
        width: navwi + "px",
        margin: "auto"
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Seems a very interesting solution! So I changed "#MSOImageWebPart_WebPartWPQ3" and "#MSOImageWebPart_WebPartWPQ11" with the ID of the web parts that I have in my page. What else do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: That was an example of one I've used. If your page has a multiple web parts. you may be able to use the below.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {


//  adjust navigation lists and  other tables to match nav bar width - Change sizes on smaller screens:
var wi = $(window).innerWidth(); 

        $(".ms-WPBody").css({
        width: wi + "px",
        margin: "auto"
        });

        $(".s4-wpTopTable").css({
        width: navwi + "px",
        margin: "auto"
        });

</script>

Comment: Unfortunately, neither the second script seems to be working. Do I need to custom anything?

Comment: What all is on your page? Is it just one webpart that you want to autosize the width of the page?

Comment: My page it's made with 5 web parts, the div id are:
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2, #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3, #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4, #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5, and #MSOZoneCell_WebPartctl00_ctl41_g_1d39b7ad_dce4_48f2_81bb_75d16951f987 
Those web parts includes a large banner. I would just like all these web parts to resize both width and height to adjust to fit the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49240/discussion-between-supertrip86-and-goldenjc97).